# Axis, Legend, and Canvas configuration in SDK?

Tags: gooddata

In the analytical designer, you can now change the configuration of the axes, legend, and canvas when creating an insight.

I know that the SDK supports setting the legend visibilty and position (https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/chart_config.html) but is it possible to configure the axis and canvas in the same way as the designer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all these configurations are available in latest alpha version and in 6.0.0-rc1 of @gooddata/react-components package, but it contains still few minor bugs. We plan to release final version of this functionality approximately in two weeks in 6.0.0 version including documentation and live examples